# BULK INSERT TASK gives following error when trying to load the data from txt file to database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

```
BULK INSERT [AG].[dbo].[tblSTAGINGTRANS]
from 'G:\Billing\Files\m2m.txt'
with (FIELDTERMINATOR='¦',ROWTERMINATOR='0x0a',CODEPAGE='ACP');

Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)"
```

I get following error. The file came from mainframe. Linux system i guess. I tried using \r\n, \n but no luck.

Can anyone please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you not missing the first \ after your drive letter?

```
BULK INSERT [AG].[dbo].[tblSTAGINGTRANS]
from 'G:\Billing\Files\m2m.txt'
with (FIELDTERMINATOR='¦',ROWTERMINATOR='0x0a',CODEPAGE='ACP');
```

Comment: Was that the issue or is it still giving that error?